# How to get Product listing filters through custom module of magento?

Tags: magento

I want to create product filters in listing pages of category using our own custom apis i have tried many things like

```
$layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
$category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($categoryid);
$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
$attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
```

But this only loads the Filterable atrribute code for the category But we want the Filters values and count for the product collection available in that category.

Below code will load all the available options of that attribute but I want it for product collection specific

```
foreach($attributes as $attribute){
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
}
```

Like we have Mobiles category having 1000s of mobiles and having filterable attribute Brand so i need

```
Brand
    Brand A (100 products)
    Brand B (500 products)
    Brand C (400 products)
```

How can this be achived if i don't want to load whole product collection as loading 1000s of product will take too much time to response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me :

```
public function ws_getfiter($store_id,$categoryid){
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);        
                $layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");

                $category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($categoryid);
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                $attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
                $filter = array();
                $count = 0;
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
                {
                    if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
                        $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_price';
                    } elseif ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'decimal') {
                        $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_decimal';
                    } else {
                        $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_attribute';
                    }
                    $filter[$count]["code"] = $attribute->attribute_code;
                    $filter[$count]["type"] =  $attribute->frontend_input;
                    $filter[$count]["label"] =  $attribute->frontend_label;
                    $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setLayer($layer)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();
                    $innercount = 0;
                    $filter_data = array();
                    foreach($result->getItems() as $option) {
                        $filter_data[$innercount]["count"] =  $option->getCount();
                        $filter_data[$innercount]["label"] =  $option->getLabel();
                        $filter_data[$innercount]["id"] =  $option->getValue();
                        $innercount++;
                    }
                    $filter[$count]["values"] = $filter_data;
                    $count++;
                }
                return $filter;
            }
```

But using this we are only getting single level of filter but i want it for multiple level.